# mysqld is not installed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql

Environment:

- `mysql-server-core-5.7`
- `myssql-client-5.7`
- `mysql-workbench 6.3.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1`
- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- Linux `4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP`

I discovered `/etc/mysql/mysql-fabric-doctrine-1.4.0.zip` and `/etc/mysql/fabric.cfg`, and no other files containing  `mysql` in the filename, nothing in the `rc*.d` in `/etc`.

Three times `apt-get remove` and `apt-get install` gave the same result.

Is it:

- a bug in install procedure?
- a problem between 32bit application and 64bit system?
- another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[digitalocean page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [nixCraft page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-linux-16-04/) explains how to install MySql 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04

The steps are:

> 1. update your system
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt upgrade
>    ```
> 2. Install both - mysql client & server
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
>    ```
>
>    > Note: You need to type the password for the MySQL root user:
> 3. Run mysql_secure_installation to secure your installation
>
>    ```
>    sudo mysql_secure_installation
>    ```
> 4. Testing MySql
>
>    ```
>    systemctl status mysql.service
>    ```
>
> You should see that it is running

Please review the full instructions in the provided links.

Comment: Something wrong : ` sudo mysql_secure_installation` :  command not found ... not include in the package

Comment: @cl-r I'm sorry,  the following install step `sudo apt installmysql-client`  should come before running `mysql_secure_installation` (it wasn't mentioned in the provided link and I missed it)