# sudo mysql_secure_installation : command not found

Tags: server, mysql

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/889609/362683) help me and I've installed `mysql-server-core-5.7` but I got an error :

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation : command not found
```

Is `mysql_secure`  not installed on ubuntu 16.04 - 64bit,  with `mysql-server-core-5.7` ?

How can I get it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqld is not installed on ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/889602/mysqld-is-not-installed-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: You could try `mariadb-secure-installation` if you're using MariaDB. Before executing that make sure MariaDB service is running

Answer (score 8):

It seems that I missed one step in the install. [This page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-linux-16-04/) helped me identifying the missing step

I've double check it, and installed it on Ubuntu 16.04, and saw that it worked.

The full steps are:

> 1. update your system
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt upgrade
>    ```
> 2. Install both - mysql client & server
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
>    ```
>
> > Note: You need to type the password for the MySQL root user:
>
> 3. Run mysql_secure_installation to secure your installation
>
>    ```
>    sudo mysql_secure_installation
>    ```

Comment: Which page are you quoting? And I suppose it would be better if you edited your original answer and closed this as a dupe of that.