# How do I log in as root in MySQL?

Tags: login, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've installed MySQL and during installation I was asked for a password which I entered, but now my teacher says that we should be able to log in as root without any password.

This works but I don't get any privileges:

[image: login prompt username phpmyadmin]

This doesn't work:

[image: login prompt username root, password has been entered, no access]

Neither does this

[image: login prompt, username root, no password, no access]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo mysql\_secure\_installation : command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889727/sudo-mysql-secure-installation-command-not-found)

Comment: Also Take a look here:[how to reset mysql root password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489098/unable-to-reset-root-password-of-mysql)

Comment: Open a terminal, run `mysql -u root -p` enter the password. Can you login there?

Comment: @kulfy I am getting "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: That means you've entered wrong password. Which Ubuntu version are you using? How did you installed mysql? I tried installing MySQL in Ubuntu that I use in virtuabox and haven't got any prompt to set a password.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.10 i followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04 as no guide for 18.10 was available.

Answer (score 17):

## Cause of the issue

The default configuration for logging in as `root` user in MySQL 5.7 requires use of an authentication socket. This can be verified via querying the `user` table:

```sql
mysql> select user,authentication_string,plugin from user where user='root';
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
| user | authentication_string | plugin      |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
| root |                       | auth_socket |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html):

> The socket plugin checks whether the socket user name (the operating
>   system user name) matches the MySQL user name specified by the client
>   program to the server. If the names do not match, the plugin checks
>   whether the socket user name matches the name specified in the
>   authentication_string column of the mysql.user system table row. If a
>   match is found, the plugin permits the connection.

In other words, mysql by default doesn't have root password set - you need to either run phpMyAdmin as root or via `sudo` (both of which are bad idea for security reasons), or you change the authentication method and reset the root password as shown in [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password).

Note that aside from same name, MySQL users and system users are not the same. You can have a MySQL user `jdoe` and have no such user on the host system. Thus, `root` is MySQL's root user, not system user.

## Steps to change plugin and password:

1. open terminal and run `sudo mysql -u root`. You should see a greeting message and `mysql>` prompt. This is the MySQL shell, which is different from your command-line shell, so only SQL statements are accepted here.
2. Enter the following sequence of SQL queries:

   ```sql
   mysql> use mysql
   Reading table information for completion of table and column names
   You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

   Database changed
   mysql> flush privileges;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql>  UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password',authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user = 'root';
   Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
   ```
3. Exit and attempt to sign in:

   ```sql
   mysql> exit
   Bye

   $ sudo systemctl restart mysql
   $ sudo mysql -u root -p
   Enter password: 
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 5
   Server version: 5.7.21-1 (Debian)

   Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

   Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
   owners.

   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

   mysql>
   ```

If everything goes well, you should be able to sign in from phpMyAdmin via the new password. If something goes wrong, attempt to restart the server without permission checking (that's step num. 3 in the Digital Ocean tutorial). For other issues, feel free to ask another question here or on [Database Administrators - Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The problem is that i can enter the CLI for mysql  if i type >sudo mysql  i get >ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @SagnikDas Command is `sudo mysql -u root`. You used `sudo mysql` which is incomplete.

Comment: The answer by Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy worked for me but I had to do an additional restart at the end ( systemctl restart mysql )

Comment: can you share answer which works for mysql 8