# MySQL asks for root password but I was never asked to set one during installation

Tags: mysql, password

I installed MySQL (fresh) on my Ubuntu 18.04. And I'm having problems logging into the database. During installation there was no request for password and when I try

```
mysql -u root -p
```

the password was somehow set and I do not not how it is possible as it's a fresh installation.

Because I was confused, I tried removing MySQL packages as was somewhere suggested

```
sudo apt-get remove -y mysql-*
sudo apt-get purge -y mysql-*
```

After this I made a new installation

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but the result is the same. Not possible to login as root without password. I went through many discussions about root password reset and no success.

I tried to start mysql server with special init file via

```
mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

the file consisted of

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('pass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

result is

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I also tried

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

5.7. is correct version of my mysql server, but no result - as I read in another discussion this is possibly obsolete solution but I tried it anyway.

I also tried

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but the new password does not work at all.

During installation there should be a request for root password, right? Or how can the password be set in the new installation? I'm quite new to Linux but I would expect that reinstall with purge should remove all settings and the new installation should be without root password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **Set, Change and reset** your root password On Ubuntu with 4 steps simply :

1. Stop your server with init.d

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. Start with mysqld configuration

   `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables $`
3. Login as root

   `mysql -u root mysql`
4. Replace your new password

   `UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE user=root;`
   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
   `EXIT;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changing password is not enough. MySQL accounts have specific login methods. Specifically, `root` account is setup such way that the socket via which you connect to `mysql` has to be owned by root. In order for password to work you also have to change which login method ( aka plugin ) the account uses. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1105982/295286

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yo're right, i check it before the OP's question marked as duplicate. should i delete it?

Comment: No, you can just click `edit` button right above our comments and add that information to your answer. There's no need to delete. People still can find duplicate  posts and  the answer can be useful for them

Comment: Thanks to @SergiyKolodyazhnyy , your link to askubuntu.com/a/1105982/295286 helped and I can now work with the database :-)

Comment: @PetrJ. Awesome ! Have fun making SQL queries and don't forget the closing `;` in the queries  :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you actually installed MariaDB? If so, you can get root (or sudo) and log in like this:

```
sudo mysql
```

That should get you in.

Comment: Whether it's MariaDB or MySQL is irrelevant in this case, MariaDB and MySQL work the same in this regard. However, the answer is pretty much correct. By default `root` account in MySQL is set up with `auth_socket` plugin, so the connection socket has to be owned by `root` and that's what `sudo` will do.  Note also that `root` in MySQL is internal account, it has nothing to do with either `sudo` or `root` on the host system itself.