# How to get mysql initial root password?

Tags: mysql, password

After installing mysql using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, no question was asked to me to fill a specific password for root account. Logically, it means password is empty. It is confirmed when I have a look in the /var/log/mysql/error.log where I can find this information =>

```
2019-04-28T20:31:35.761063Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

But now, when I connect to PHPAdmin with root login and empty password, I have a message:

```
#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

with a few more details:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please see [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html)

Comment: See `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server/NEWS.Debian.gz`.

Comment: sudo mysql_secure_installation

Answer (score 22):

With Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql-5.7, the default method for a mysql root login has changed,
now you have to be the superuser (either by doing `sudo mysql -u root` or by calling a root shell `sudo bash` first). Since you are already authenticated as the root user, no password is needed any longer.

See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105970/how-do-i-log-in-as-root-in-mysq) and its answers.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the password and set a new root password by doing this :

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

skip-grant-tables option enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges

Comment: this did not work for me.  mysqld would exit with no errors if I tried this.

Comment: this never works, with any version of MySQL (5.7, 8.0)
When you try to connect you always get:


ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: adding `--skip-grant-tables` as a command line argumnet doesn't seem to work, but it works when you add `skip-grant-tables` to the configuration files, e.g. after the `[mysqld]` line in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf`